# Can Facebook Graph API only return n entry?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to place a Graph Api call, which returns only n entries, where n is the number of result entries I would like? For example limiting it to 5 or 10, not all as the default.

Something similar to the `SQL Select * .... LIMIT n`.

I haven't found anything on the FB Dev Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use the `limit` parameter:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?limit=3`

EDIT: see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ : look at the **Paging** section.

Comment: Okay thanks, but so far I tested it, it won't work on checkins

Comment: When you say it won't work, you mean it returns more checkins than the limit you specified?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to say ;-)